# Java: find the main class of a JAR file on a website

Tags: java, url, jar, program-entry-point

I am writing a program that connects to a web host that has a directory containing a couple JAR files. Then, a GUI shows the JAR name and when you double click on the name, it will open the JAR file.

The problem that I am having is, not all of the JAR files have the main method in the same place, so I need some way of finding the main class.

I have tried doing an approach like this:

```
    File file = new File("website/test.jar");
    JarFile jar = new JarFile(file);
    String mainClass = jar.getManifest().getMainAttributes().get("Main-Class").toString();
```

However, I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
```

On the line where a JarFile object is created. I have thought of two solutions: go through all the class files in the JAR and search for the one that contains the main method, or create a text file in the directory that tells the main file of each JAR.

I would prefer to use the first solution, because it does not actually require me to do extra steps every time I upload another JAR. However, I am concerned that it is kind of a "brute-force" alternative, and it feels inefficient.

Have any of you experienced a similar problems?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this : 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/jarclassloader.html

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I missed this. This does exactly what I wanted - thanks a ton!